# On-Call Notify with Twilio

Tags: sms, twilio, voice, notify, servicenow

I am trying to configure on-call scheduling notify with Twilio to make REST API call for SMS and Phone call. We are using OOB workflow “On-Call: Assign and Notify”. This workflow has block called Send SMS notification. How can we pass Incident information to assigned group on call person through Twilio phone number? Any sample scripts help to modify below block.

Thanks,
Ranjith

Comment: Is this a code question? Or is this more to do with configuration in servicenow? Can you share what you've done so far?

Comment: I am trying to configure on-call scheduling notify with Twilio to make REST API call for SMS and Phone call. We are using OOB workflow “On-Call: Assign and Notify”. This workflow has block called Send SMS notification. How can we pass Incident information to assigned group on call person through Twilio phone number? Any sample scripts help to modify below block.

Comment: I am looking for sample scripts for SMS, this is want it shows up in workflow.

Comment: I am looking for sample scriptsSMS,this is whatitshowsup in workflow.result = getRecipientsAndNumberToSendFrom();
/*Generate the object thatwillconfigure what number tosend
*theSMS fromand to what additional phone numbers orusers
*theSMS should be sent.*@returns{{notify_number:*, users: Array, groups: Array,numbers: Array}}*/ function getRecipientsAndNumberToSendFrom(){return {//notify_number : getNotifyNumber(),//the sys_id of the notify numberusers:[current.getValue("assigned_to")],//array of user ids groups: [],//array of group ids numbers : []  //array of E164 compliant phone numbers};}

Comment: /*FunctiontodeterminetheNotifyNumbertocallfromNote,THISLOGICSHOULDPROBABLYCHANGEasitwill return the first notify numberwhich may not even be a SMS capable number.
@returns {*}
function getNotifyNumber() {//ifthis workflowisrunningin the context of the call table, use the notifynumberassociated
if(current.getTableName() == 'notify_call')
return current.notify_number;
//getthefirstnotifynumberTHISSHOULDPROBABLYCHANGE!
var number = new GlideRecord('notify_number');
number.query();
if (number.next())
return number.getUniqueValue();
return null;}

Answer (score 0):

In the "**Send Notify SMS**" workflow activity you specify the message to be sent.  You can use variables in that message to pass information from the incident.

`${sys_class_name} ${number}` has been assigned to you: `${short_description}`

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: add it as a comment if you don't understand